# How does Visual Studio display a System.Double during debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, double

Try debugging the following simple program, and mouse over `x` in each step (or "Add Watch" for `x` or whatever).

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

static class Program
{
  static double x;

  static void Main()
  {
    x = 2d;

    // now debugger shows "2.0", as if it has used
    // x.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    x = 8.0 / 7.0;

    // now debugger shows "1.1428571428571428", as if it had used
    // x.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    // Note that 17 significant figures are shown, not the usual 15.

    x = -1e-200 / 1e200;

    // now debugger shows "0.0"; there is no indication that this is really negative zero
    //

    Console.WriteLine(1.0 / x); // this is negative infinity
  }
}
```

So, apparently VS has its own way to display a `System.Double`. Which method does it call for this purpose? Is there a way I can get the very same string representation programmatically?

(Tried this out with Visual Studio 2010 Professional.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At their core both the C# and VB.Net EE's use the `_ecvt_s` function for formatting a `double` into a string.

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehz2dset(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehz2dset%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Both do a little bit of cleanup on the resulting string to make the display more C# and VB like and handle some corner cases a bit nicer.  Either the `_ecvt_s` function or the cleanup code could be responsible for the differences you see.  Hard to tell at a glance

Some may ask why we would go through all of this trouble instead of saying just calling `ToString` on the value and displaying that.  There are a couple of reasons we don't do this.

The first is simply that function evaluation, even `ToString`, is the single most expensive action the EE can undertake.  Profiles of common real scenarios show that over 98% of our time was spent doing function evaluation.  Any time we can avoid a func eval we do because of the performance implications.

The second reason is simply that function evaluation isn't always available. There are a number of cases where func eval is unavailable yet people still expect to see a display for primitive types like `double`, `int`, etc ... Taking them away would essentially kill the debugging experience.  Hence we need to solve this problem without `ToString` support.

Comment: Very informative answer. But it does not really tell my **how** `_ecvt_s` is called. And I suspect that the `ToString` methods also work by eventually calling `_ecvt_s`? Also, adding the ".0" part to the string is probably done by what you call the cleanup code, so me calling `_ecvt_s` through some `extern` method would not do the job alone. So maybe the answer is simply: No, I cannot get the same string programmatically?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen not quite sure what you mean by how _ecvt_s is called. Could you elaborate?  As for getting the exact same string yourself, yes it's difficult to replicate unless you have the exact cleanup code handy.

Comment: I'm not sure how the output from `_ecvt_s` depends on the parameters, like `_SizeInBytes`, and `_Count`. But the string shown by VS seems to include always at least one digit to the right of the decimal point, but otherways has no trailing zeroes. The reason why they do the ".0" thing is certainly that it makes it more clear that it is not an `Int32` but a `Double`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen the 0 to the right appears to be a part of the clean up code.

Answer (score 2):

I will accept JaredPar's answer since it describes how things work inside the debugger.

But because the answer does not help to get the same string, here is some code that often (always?) gives the same string:

```
static string ToDebugString(this double d)
{
  if (Double.IsNaN(d) || Double.IsInfinity(d))
    return d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

  string s = d.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  if (!s.Contains("."))
    s += ".0";
  return s;
}
```

Please feel free to improve this answer.

---

EDIT: This is an old post that deals with `ToString` as it was (is) in .NET Framework and .NET Core up to 2.2. Starting with .NET Core 3.0 from 2019 and continuing in .NET 5, .NET 6, .NET 7 and so on, the behavior of `ToString` [has changed a lot](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/).