# Printing double values

Tags: c#

On my system, the following code prints '3.6':

```
double a = 1.2;
int b = 3;

double c = a * b;

Console.WriteLine(c);
```

But in the debugger, I can see that `c` has a value with more than 2 digits:

[image]

I know that I can display the full representation with `Console.WriteLine("{0:R}", c)`. Is this the only and recommended way to display the actual value of a `double`?

---

**update**

Going with the above example, I'd like to print `c` such that if the user were to take the printed value and insert that back into the code in a test using `==`, the comparison would be true. In this case `c == 3.5999999999999996` returns true.

Comment: How you display depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: how many decimal places are you wanting to display..?

Comment: Notice for other answerers: the real question is about comparing doubles, not about formatting the output. I'd advise @dharmatech to update their question.

Answer (score 8):

`Console.WriteLine` calls `Double.ToString` which uses the the ["G" format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString). This uses the current culture to determine the number of decimal places (1 for "en-US").

If you want to display 8 decimal places you can use the [numeric format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString):

```
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("N8"));
```

[**Standard Numeric Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k.aspx)

**Edit**: The debugger uses this method to convert a double to a string:

[**_ecvt_s**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehz2dset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I assume it's the cheapest way to convert it.

Where i have found it: [How does Visual Studio display a System.Double during debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252030/284240)

Comment: Hi Tim. I'd like to display the value that appears in the debugger. Using "N8" or even "N20" doesn't display that value.

Comment: @dharmatech: Edited my answer. Why do you want to diplay it the same as the debugger?

Comment: I'd like to display the value such that if that value is then taken and turned used with `==`, the test will be true. E.g. in this case `c == 3.5999999999999996` does indeed return true.

Comment: @dharmatech: you are going into dangerous territory. Read this: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Answer (score 8):

3.999999999999996 is not the actual value of the double either; that's just the value rounded off to fifteen places or whatever.  There is no built-in way to display the actual *exact* value that the double is representing. This is really too bad, because every normal double can be represented exactly as a decimal string, and it would be nice to be able to see that.

As a public service, I've put source code for a device which does that on my blog:

http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/17/looking-inside-a-double/

Note that it uses the Rational class from Microsoft Solver Foundation. If you don't have that then you can either download it for free, or write your own Rational class; it's character-building to do so.

If the subject of how doubles work internally interests you, consider checking out my archive of handy articles explaining all that. It's at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/floating+point+arithmetic/

Start from the bottom; those are in reverse-chronological order.

Comment: Funny that you mention rolling your own `Rational` class. My project that this question resulted from has its own Rationals. Ultimately, it would be great to have the C# version of [CLN](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/). It would be nice if in the future, mainstream languages come with such a complete numeric tower.

Comment: I updated the question with my actual goal, since someone asked.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a different approach for example if you want to return 2 decimal places you could try something like this

```
double a = 1.2;
int b = 3;
double c = a * b;
var s = string.Format("{0:0.00}", c);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

> Output = 3.60

if you want to suppress the last 0 where out put is 3.6 you could do

```
var s = string.Format("{0:0.##}", c);
```

> Output = 3.6 feel free to play around with it

Comment: won't the ## suppress both zeroes?    
It Should be : 
'var s = string.Format("{0:0.0#}", c);'

Answer (score 1):

```
double a = 1.2;
int b = 3;

double c = a * b;
string formatted = c.ToString("N5");
Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```